# Reference a workbook with varying filenames

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code running which on a key stroke will open another workbook and copy data into a table from the original workbook. This is working when the original workbook name is the same. However, the workbook with the initial code will have a different name. When I have tried to run the code with a different file name a file explorer popup appears, this is not what I want.

I have tried to create a variable for the workbook name and using that, however, this has not worked.

below is the code I have used which has not been successful thus far.

```
'Get the name and path of this file name

 Dim route As String
    Dim book As String

    route = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    book = ActiveWorkbook.Name


'open the workbook to save the data

'make a new line item which works

'Reference Requester where "book" is the variable above which is not working

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[book]ARF!R6C4"
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

What i want the code to do is copy the data from the original file and save it onto the central database by taking out a line item and then populating the data. Then to avoid all the data referencing the most recent file I copied and Past special as value for the data.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I now get an error that i have put "book" in the [] instead of the file name.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `book` as a variable, but in the reference you're using it as a `String`. Change it to the following:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[" & book & "]ARF!R6C4"
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but I am now getting the a run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: You might have to use `book = ActiveWorkbook.FullName` depending on where your workbooks are placed.

Comment: I tried this, which got me past the error. However, now it requires me to select a file from a pop up. with the title update variable: book